# Is it correct to use the verb " phone" in the passive form?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, active-voice

In case of an active sentence formed by a verb + indirect object, may it be transformed into passive sentence or not?

For example, could the following sentence be turned into passive?

> Claire phoned her father yesterday

Comment: Okay, so Claire indeed was a girl. Phew :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your subtle correction :-) and thank you for answering!

Comment: You're very welcome. That's what we're here for.

Comment: @TusharRaj [Clair Huffaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clair_Huffaker), the well known writer of Westerns, was a dude.;-)

Comment: @Cascabel: Haha. And that's why I never assume anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible.

[From *The Death Relic*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SV8UpBm84tQC&pg=PT284&dq=%22was%20phoned%20by%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi90tOpmefRAhUkTI8KHSHwA98Q6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22was%20phoned%20by%22&f=false) by Chris Kuzneski:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Technically it would be
"Claire's father was phoned by her yesterday."

Even though there ample evidence of such usage; it seems clumsy at best and certainly not formal language.

A better way of rephrasing the same could be:

"Claire's father received a call from her yesterday."